# How to parse the Google Places API for City, State, Country code and Zip details?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm parsing the google places api for specific format of address. But I'm getting null values after parsing. I want the address format be like: `Mumbai, Maharashtra, IN, 400047`. For that I'm saving the param `types` of `address_components` into ArrayList and then checking for specific string. But I'm getting null as values.

```html
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("OK")) {
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                            for(int k=0;k<array.length();k++){
                                JSONObject jObj = array.getJSONObject(0);
                                JSONArray jarr = jObj.getJSONArray("address_components");
                                for(int i=0; i<jarr.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject jobj = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String long_name = jobj.getString("long_name");
                                    String short_name = jobj.getString("short_name");
                                    JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("types");
                                    for(int j=0; j<jarray.length();j++){
                                        typo.add(jarray.getString(j));
                                        if(Arrays.asList(typo).contains("administrative_area_level_2")){
                                            cityStr = long_name;
                                        }else if(Arrays.asList(typo).contains("administrative_area_level_1")){
                                            stateStr = long_name;
                                        }else if(Arrays.asList(typo).contains("country")){
                                            countryStr = short_name;
                                        }else if(Arrays.asList(typo).contains("postal_code")){
                                            zipStr = long_name;
                                        }

                                    }


                                }
                            }

                            result = cityStr + ", " + stateStr + ", " + zipStr + ", " + countryStr;
                          


                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried so many things. In the end what worked for me is `optString()`. Using optString, I'm checking the array parameter `types`.

```html
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("OK")) {
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                            for(int k=0;k<array.length();k++){
                                JSONObject jObj = array.getJSONObject(0);
                                JSONArray jarr = jObj.getJSONArray("address_components");
                                for(int i=0; i<jarr.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject jobj = jarr.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String long_name = jobj.getString("long_name");
                                    String short_name = jobj.getString("short_name");
                                    JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("types");
                                    for(int j=0; j<jarray.length();j++){
                                        String object = jarray.optString(j);
                                        if(object.equals("administrative_area_level_2")){
                                            cityStr = long_name;
                                            System.out.println("sammy_city "+cityStr);
                                        }
                                        if(object.equals("administrative_area_level_1")){
                                            stateStr = long_name;
                                            System.out.println("sammy_state "+stateStr);
                                        }
                                        if(object.equals("country")){
                                            countryStr = short_name;
                                            System.out.println("sammy_country "+countryStr);
                                        }
                                        if(object.equals("postal_code")){
                                            zipStr = long_name;
                                            System.out.println("sammy_zip "+zipStr);
                                        }

                                    }


                                }
                            }

                            result = cityStr + ", " + stateStr + ", " + zipStr + ", " + countryStr;
```